# Using useLocation of React-Router-DOM to receive passed data in React results in manually inputted links not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-router, react-router-dom

Initially, it works if the manually input link is wrong (Ex: `"/characters/test"`), but if it's the correct one, it still redirects to error 404. If the link is clicked from `Character` component, it works normally. Which means no matter what link I put manually on the browser, it results in error 404.

I've been trying to implement an error 404 redirect on a `CharacterCard` component by comparing the id being passed - 'name' (as `useParams`) and comparing it to an characterId list from another component being passed, if it matches, then it renders normally, if not, it redirects to error 404.

Since I'm using React-Router v6, I can't pass props normally as far as I know. After a bit of research, I found out I can use `Link` state to pass data to another component it links to and `useLocation` to get the passed data. I successfully passed data to the component, but then it results to the problem I stated above.

Codesandbox link for reproducibility:
https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/funny-platform-xdlgkk

App.js (Route Declarations)

```
import { Route, Routes } from 'react-router-dom';
import './App.css';
import { Nations } from './components/Nations';
import { Navbar } from './components/Navbar';
import { Characters } from './components/Characters';
import { Home } from './components/Home';
import { Artifacts } from './components/Artifacts';
import { Weapons } from './components/Weapons';
import { CharacterCard } from './components/CharacterCard';
import { NotFound } from './components/NotFound';


function App() {

  return (
    <div className='bg-[#1e1f21]'>
      <Navbar />
      <Routes>
        <Route path='/' element={<Home/>}/>
        <Route path='/nations' element={<Nations/>}/>
        <Route path='/weapons' element={<Weapons/>}/>
        <Route path='/characters' element={<Characters/>}/>
        <Route path='/characters/:name' element={<CharacterCard/>}/>
        <Route path='/artifacts' element={<Artifacts/>}/>
        <Route path="*" element={<NotFound/>}/>
      </Routes>
      
    </div>
  );
}


export default App;
```

Characters

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { PuffLoader } from "react-spinners";

const API_URL = 'something.somethin.com';
const CDN_URL = 'something2.somethin2.com';

export const Characters = () => {
  const [characters, setCharacters] = useState([]);
  const [isLoaded, setIsLoaded] = useState(false);

  const validCharacterIds = characters.map((character) => character.id);
  console.log('valid ids:', validCharacterIds);
  const getCharacters = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await fetch({API_URL});
      const charactersData = await response.json();

      const characterDetailsData = await Promise.all(
        charactersData.map(async (character) => {
          const characterDetails = await getCharacterDetails(character);
          return characterDetails;
        })
      );

      setCharacters(characterDetailsData);
      console.log('characters: ', characterDetailsData);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("Error fetching Characters:", error);
    }
  };

  const getCharacterDetails = async (character) => {
    //code for getCharacterDetails

    setIsLoaded(true);
    return { ...characterDetailsData, id:character, icon: imageData };
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getCharacters();
    document.title = "Characters | Website Title"
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className='w-full py-[3rem] px-4 bg-white'>
      //Character Card that when clicked opens CharacterCard Component
      <div className='w-[500px] md:w-[1200px] mx-auto grid grid-cols-1 md:grid-cols-5 gap-5'>
        {isLoaded ? (
          (characters.length > 0) ? (
            characters.map((character) => (
              <Link key={character.name} to={`/characters/${character.id}`} state={{charIds: validCharacterIds}} className='w-full shadow-xl flex flex-col my-4 rounded-lg hover:scale-105 duration-300'>
                <div className={
                  character.rarity === 4
                    ? "bg-gradient-to-b from-[#5e5789] to-[#9c75b7]"
                    : character.rarity === 5
                      ? "bg-gradient-to-b from-[#945c2c] to-[#b27330]"
                      : ''
                }>
                  <img className='w-[300px] h-[250px] object-cover' src={character.icon} alt={character.name + ' Icon'} />
                </div>
                <div>
                  <h4 className='text-2xl font-bold text-center py-8'>{character.name}</h4>
                </div>
              </Link>
            ))
          ) : (
            <div className='empty'>
              <h2>No Characters Found!</h2>
            </div>
          )
        ) : (
          <div className="flex justify-center items-center">
            <PuffLoader color="#36d7b7" />
          </div>
        )}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

CharacterCard

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { useNavigate, Navigate, useParams, useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';
import { PuffLoader } from 'react-spinners';
import Carousel from './Carousel';

const CDN_URL = 'somethin.somethin.com';
const API_URL = 'somethin2.somethin2.com';

export const CharacterCard = () => {
  const [characterDetails, setCharacterDetails] = useState(null);

  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const { name } = useParams();
  const location = useLocation();
  let validCharIds = location.state;
  console.log(location);

  const getCharacterDetails = async (characterName) => {
    //rest of the api fetch goes here
  };


  useEffect(() => {
    const checkValidCharId = async () => {
      if (!validCharIds || !validCharIds.charIds || !validCharIds.charIds.includes(name)) {
        // Redirect to error 404 if the name is not in the validCharIds array or empty
        navigate('*');
        console.log('error 404');
      } else {
        // Fetch character details only if the name is valid
        await getCharacterDetails(name);
      }
    };

    checkValidCharId();
  }, [name, validCharIds, navigate]);



  if(characterDetails) {
      return (
      //Render component normally

    );
  }

  else {
    return (
      <div className='flex justify-center items-center'>
         <Navigate to='*'/>
      </div>
    )
  }

};
```

Example Data:
validCharacterIds
[image: validCharacterIds data for mapping]

Characters
[image: Characters array after fetch]

Comment: Please [edit] to share the route declarations and example data that you are mapping over and rendering links. See [mcve].

Comment: I have edited the post as needed, is this what you are looking for?

Comment: Yes, that looks like what I requested, thank you. It seems the `id` property is already a string value, so I don't see any overt reason for the current logic to not work. Question though, if the `Character` component already fetched the character data, why not just pass it in route state instead of just the id and refetch it again in the `CharacterCard` component? Otherwise, see if you can create a ***running*** [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) demo of your code that reproduces the issue that we could inspect live.

Comment: May i ask how I can implement your suggestion?

I have also setup a codesandbox demo for the project:
https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/funny-platform-xdlgkk

within the codesandbox, access via this link https://xdlgkk.csb.app/characters, then try clicking the characters and it should load its charactercard properly, but then try putting the corrrect url manually in the browser and it will result to a error 404

Comment: The code in your sandbox appears to function correctly. I can navigate from `"/characters"` to a specific character's page, and if trying to manually navigate to one the `NotFound` component is rendered as I'd expect per the code in `CharacterCard`. Are you saying that you want `CharacterCard` to load the correct data regardless how the user got there?

Comment: Yes that is my desired outcome, that even if the user puts a valid/correct link manually for character it still loads correctly and not redirect to NotFound

Comment: Ok, I see. I've updated my answer below with a suggested refactor. Please do take a look when you have time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For what you describe, manually entering a character name in the URL path, the code is functioning correctly. This is because the `CharacterCard` component is expecting the user to have navigated to it's page via the `"/characters"` route such that all the characters data was fetched and the array of valid character names could be passed in route state when navigating from `"/characters"` to `"/characters/:name"`. When you manually edit the address bar to navigate directly to `"/characters/:name"` the route state is null. This can only be generated via the `Link` and navigation action from one page to the other.

Unfortunately another issue with the logic is even after a valid loading of all the character data and navigation to the character detail page, if the user refreshes/reloads the page, the characters state will be reset, including the array of valid ids, and the user will be bounced off the route.

> My desired outcome, that even if the user puts a valid/correct link
> manually for character it still loads correctly and not redirect to
> NotFound

My suggestion here would be to create a layout route component that fetches and holds character data so that it can be loaded regardless of which `"/characters/*"` sub-route the user is on. Make `"/characters/:name"` wait to be mounted/rendered until *after* the characters data is fetched and available, then make the call for details only after it is determined the id is valid.

Example:

CharactersLayout.jsx - Move the character fetching and loading logic to the layout route component and provide the state out on the `Outlet` Context provider.

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { Outlet } from "react-router-dom";
import { PuffLoader } from "react-spinners";

const API_URL = "https://genshin.jmp.blue";
const CDN_URL = "https://cdn.wanderer.moe/genshin-impact";

export const CharactersLayout = () => {
  const [characters, setCharacters] = useState([]);
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);

  const getCharacters = async () => {
    setIsLoading(true);
    try {
      const response = await fetch(`${API_URL}/characters/`);
      const charactersData = await response.json();

      const characterDetailsData = await Promise.all(
        charactersData.map(getCharacterDetails)
      );

      setCharacters(characterDetailsData);
    } catch (error) {
    } finally {
      setIsLoading(false);
    }
  };

  const getCharacterDetails = async (character) => {
    const detailsResponse = await fetch(`${API_URL}/characters/${character}`);
    const characterDetailsData = await detailsResponse.json();

    const imageResponse = await fetch(
      `${CDN_URL}/character-icons/ui-avataricon-${character}.png`
    );
    let imageData;

    if (imageResponse.status === 404) {
      try {
        const altImageResponse = await fetch(
          `${API_URL}/characters/${character}/icon-big`
        );
        if (altImageResponse.ok) {
          imageData = await altImageResponse.url;
        } else {
          imageData =
            "https://mosmandentistry.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/orionthemes-placeholder-image-2.png";
        }
      } catch (error) {
        imageData =
          "https://mosmandentistry.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/orionthemes-placeholder-image-2.png";
      }
    } else {
      imageData = await imageResponse.url;
    }

    return { ...characterDetailsData, id: character, icon: imageData };
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getCharacters();
  }, []);

  const validCharacterIds = characters.map(({ id }) => id);

  return isLoading ? (
    <div className="flex justify-center items-center">
      <p>Fetching characters</p>
      <PuffLoader color="#36d7b7" />
    </div>
  ) : (
    <Outlet
      context={{
        characters,
        isLoadingCharacters: isLoading,
        validCharacterIds
      }}
    />
  );
};
```

Character.jsx - Read `characters` array provided from `Outlet` Context. Don't pass any link state.

```
import { useEffect } from "react";
import { Link, useOutletContext } from "react-router-dom";

export const Characters = () => {
  const { characters } = useOutletContext();

  useEffect(() => {
    document.title = "Characters | Kagerou.info";
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="w-full py-[3rem] px-4 bg-white">
      <h1 className="py-5 md:text-5xl sm:text-6xl text-4xl font-bold md:py-10 font-genshin text-center">
        Characters
      </h1>
      <div className="w-[500px] md:w-[1200px] mx-auto grid grid-cols-1 md:grid-cols-5 gap-5">
        {characters.length ? (
          characters.map((character) => (
            <Link
              key={character.id}
              to={`/characters/${character.id}`}
              className="w-full shadow-xl flex flex-col my-4 rounded-lg hover:scale-105 duration-300"
            >
              <div
                className={
                  character.rarity === 4
                    ? "bg-gradient-to-b from-[#5e5789] to-[#9c75b7]"
                    : character.rarity === 5
                    ? "bg-gradient-to-b from-[#945c2c] to-[#b27330]"
                    : ""
                }
              >
                <img
                  className="w-[300px] h-[250px] object-cover"
                  src={character.icon}
                  alt={character.name + " Icon"}
                />
              </div>
              <div>
                <h4 className="text-2xl font-bold text-center py-8">
                  {character.name}
                </h4>
              </div>
            </Link>
          ))
        ) : (
          <div className="empty">
            <h2>No Characters Found!</h2>
          </div>
        )}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

CharacterCard.jsx - Read the provided `validCharacterIds` value provided by the `Outlet` Context and conditionally fetch the character details.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import {
  useNavigate,
  Navigate,
  useParams,
  useOutletContext
} from "react-router-dom";
import { PuffLoader } from "react-spinners";

const CDN_URL = "https://cdn.wanderer.moe/genshin-impact";
const API_URL = "https://genshin.jmp.blue";

export const CharacterCard = () => {
  const { validCharacterIds } = useOutletContext();
  const { id } = useParams();

  const [characterDetails, setCharacterDetails] = useState(null);
  const [characterImages, setCharacterImages] = useState([]);
  const [imageLoaded, setImageLoaded] = useState(false);
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);

  const getCharacterDetails = async (characterName) => {
    setIsLoading(true);
    try {
      if (validCharacterIds.includes(id)) {
        const detailsResponse = fetch(`${API_URL}/characters/${characterName}`);
        const nameCardResponse = fetch(
          `${CDN_URL}/namecards/ui-namecardpic-${characterName}-p.png`
        );
        const iconResponse = fetch(
          `${CDN_URL}/character-icons/ui-avataricon-${characterName.toLowerCase()}.png`
        );
        const splashArtResponse = fetch(
          `${CDN_URL}/splash-art/${characterName.toLowerCase()}.png`
        );
        const characterCardResponse = fetch(
          `${CDN_URL}/character-cards/character-${characterName.toLowerCase()}-card.png`
        );

        const [
          details,
          nameCard,
          icon,
          splashArt,
          characterCard
        ] = await Promise.all([
          detailsResponse,
          nameCardResponse,
          iconResponse,
          splashArtResponse,
          characterCardResponse
        ]);

        const characterDetailsData = await details.json();

        let nobgImageData;
        let queryName;
        queryName = characterDetailsData.name.replace(" ", "-");
        let nobgImage = await fetch(
          `${CDN_URL}/character-icons/ui-avataricon-${queryName.toLowerCase()}.png`
        );

        if (nobgImage.ok) {
          nobgImageData = nobgImage.url;
        } else {
          nobgImage = await fetch(
            `${API_URL}/characters/${queryName.toLowerCase()}/icon-big`
          );
          // const nobgImage = await fetch(`${CDN_URL}/character-icons/ui-avataricon-${queryName.toLowerCase()}.png`);
          nobgImageData = nobgImage.url;
        }

        setCharacterImages({
          banner: nameCard.ok
            ? (await nameCard.url) || nameCard.headers.get("location")
            : "",
          icon: nobgImageData,
          splashArt: splashArt.url,
          characterCard: characterCard.url
        });
        setCharacterDetails(characterDetailsData);
        setImageLoaded(true);

        console.log("Character Details: ", characterDetailsData);

        // Set Page title as Character Name
        document.title = id;
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error fetching character details:", error);
    } finally {
      setIsLoading(false);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getCharacterDetails(id);
  }, [id]);

  if (isLoading) {
    return (
      <div className="flex justify-center items-center">
        <p>Fetching {id}</p>
        <PuffLoader color="#36d7b7" />
      </div>
    );
  }

  if (!characterDetails) {
    return <Navigate to="/404" replace />;
  }

  return (
    // Nothing changed in rendered content here
  );
};
```

App.jsx - Render `CharactersLayout` as a parent layout route to the two existing routes.

```
import { Route, Routes, Navigate } from "react-router-dom";
import { CharactersLayout } from "./CharactersLayout";
import { Characters } from "./Characters";
import { CharacterCard } from "./CharacterCard";
import { NotFound } from "./NotFound";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="bg-[#1e1f21]">
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/characters" element={<CharactersLayout />}>
          <Route index element={<Characters />} />
          <Route path=":id" element={<CharacterCard />} />
        </Route>
        <Route path="404" element={<NotFound />} />
        <Route path="*" element={<Navigate to="/404" replace />} />
      </Routes>
    </div>
  );
}
```

### Demo

[image: Edit using-uselocation-of-react-router-dom-to-receive-passed-data-in-react-results-in]

Comment: Thank you very much for you solution! It works, and a better implementation on redirecting error 404's than mine.

Answer (score 0):

The issue you're facing might be related to the way you're using the state prop in the Link component. Instead of relying on the state prop of the Link component, you can use a different approach to pass data to the CharacterCard component. You can update the to prop of the Link component to include the character id as a parameter in the route:

```
<Link key={character.name} to={`/characters/${character.id}?charIds=${validCharacterIds.join(',')}`} className='w-full shadow-xl flex flex-col my-4 rounded-lg hover:scale-105 duration-300'>
```

This way, you're passing the charIds as a query parameter in the URL. Then, in the CharacterCard component, you can retrieve this query parameter using useParams:

```
const { name } = useParams();
const charIds = new 
URLSearchParams(useLocation().search).get('charIds')?.split(',');

useEffect(() => {
  const checkValidCharId = async () => {
    if (!charIds || !charIds.includes(name)) {
      navigate('*');
  console.log('error 404');
} else {
  
  await getCharacterDetails(name);
 }
};

checkValidCharId();
}, [charIds, name, navigate]);
```

This way, whether the link is clicked or manually inputted, the necessary data should be available in the CharacterCard component, and the 404 redirection logic should work as expected.